# How to delete/replace a text[] value in any position

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a table with a text[] field:

```
     page_id      |                           tags
------------------+------------------------------------------------
    test_page     | {"first tag","second tag",zodd,"another tag"}
```

I want to delete the "second tag" value in the field.

I can get it work with replace if I specify the position like this:

```
select replace(tags[2],'second tag'::text,'') from test_page;
 replace
---------

(1 row)
```

But the tag may be in position 1 or 3 or any position ( and  is not limited to 4 values as in this example)

Is there a wildcard I can put to replace the [2] that will perform the replace in any position?

Comment: Jack - I've tried the replace command I have above and it will work if the tag is in the 2nd position.  However - this is targetting only this specific page - I want to be able to use a wildcard in that stmt that will work on all pages.

Answer (score 2):

If you want delete element `'second tag'` from array, you can do this:

```
select 
    page_id,
    array(select arr from unnest(tags) as arr where arr <> 'second tag')
from test_page;
```

May be there're more efficient ways to do this, don't know yet.

Comment: Had to make a slight modification to this:  select array(select arr from unnest(tags) as arr where arr <> 'second tag' ) from page - but it works perfectly - thank you very much!